# How to convert many-valued logic into efficient boolean logic?

Tags: logic, boolean-logic, karnaugh-map

Suppose that I have a set `S` consisting of `{0₁, ¯1₂, 0₂, 1₂, ¯2₃, ¯1₃, 0₃, 1₃, 2₃, ¯3₄, ¯2₄, ¯1₄, 0₄, 1₄, 2₄, 3₄}`. I want to define the following operations over `S`:

- `S < 0` which returns one if and only if `S` is negative.
- `¯S` which returns the negation of `S`.
- `S + 0` which returns `S` plus zero, which is `S` unchanged.
- `S + 1` which returns the absolute value of `S` plus one, modulo the subscript. For example:

  - Both `¯1₃ + 1` and `1₃ + 1` evaluate to `2₃`.
  - Both `¯2₃ + 1` and `2₃ + 1` evaluate to `0₃`.
  - The expression `0₃ + 1` evaluates to `1₃`.
- `S ¢ 0` which returns the [carry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_operator) of `S + 0`, which is zero.
- `S ¢ 1` which returns the carry of `S + 1`, which is one if and only if `S + 1 = 0ₙ` for `n > 1`.

This information can be captured in the form of a truth table:

```
  S  S<0 ¯S  S+0 S+1 S¢0 S¢1
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│ 0₁│ 0 │ 0₁│ 0₁│ 0₁│ 0 │ 0 │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│¯1₂│ 1 │ 1₂│¯1₂│ 0₂│ 0 │ 1 │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 0₂│ 0 │ 0₂│ 0₂│ 1₂│ 0 │ 0 │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 1₂│ 0 │¯1₂│ 1₂│ 0₂│ 0 │ 1 │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│¯2₃│ 1 │ 2₃│¯2₃│ 0₃│ 0 │ 1 │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│¯1₃│ 1 │ 1₃│¯1₃│ 2₃│ 0 │ 0 │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 0₃│ 0 │ 0₃│ 0₃│ 1₃│ 0 │ 0 │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 1₃│ 0 │¯1₃│ 1₃│ 2₃│ 0 │ 0 │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 2₃│ 0 │¯2₃│ 2₃│ 0₃│ 0 │ 1 │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│¯3₄│ 1 │ 3₄│¯3₄│ 0₄│ 0 │ 1 │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│¯2₄│ 1 │ 2₄│¯2₄│ 3₄│ 0 │ 0 │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│¯1₄│ 1 │ 1₄│¯1₄│ 2₄│ 0 │ 0 │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 0₄│ 0 │ 0₄│ 0₄│ 1₄│ 0 │ 0 │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 1₄│ 0 │¯1₄│ 1₄│ 2₄│ 0 │ 0 │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 2₄│ 0 │¯2₄│ 2₄│ 3₄│ 0 │ 0 │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 3₄│ 0 │¯3₄│ 3₄│ 0₄│ 0 │ 1 │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

What I want to do is convert this many-valued truth table into a boolean truth table so that I can implement the operations using bitwise operators for parallelization. Sounds simple enough. Assign `0000` to `0₁`, `0001` to `¯1₂`, ..., `1111` to `3₄`. Solve the resulting [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) to get a [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) or [DNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) expression and call it a day.

Unfortunately, the resulting CNF or DNF expressions might not be efficient with this naive mapping of `S` to boolean values. I want to find the most efficient way to represent this many-valued truth table as a boolean truth table. Here, efficient means using the fewest operators to implement the various operations with preference being given to addition, negation, carry and comparison in that order. However, the problem is that there are `16!` or `20922789888000` ways to map `S` to boolean values. Is there a better way to find the solution than brute force?

Comment: Shouldn't you add `1` and `0` to the left column?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean `1` and `0` should be logical values too. `1₂ + 0` is `1₂`, but what is `1 + 0`? By way, are bit shift operators allowed?

Comment: They belong to different sets. `1₂` belongs to the set `S` whereas `1` and `0` belong to the set `B` of Boolean values. The `+` operation requires that its left operand belong to set `S` and its right operand belong to set `B`. The result of the `+` operation is a value from set `S`.

Comment: No. Bit shift operators aren't allowed because each bit is going to be stored separately. The reason for this is for parallelism. For example, given a matrix of `S` values all the high bits are stored in one bit array, all the low bits are stored in another bit array, etc. Hence, bit shift operators would shift bits across values of the matrix. The idea is to use bitwise operations to perform convolutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a general solution to this problem but here's a specific solution for my problem. We begin by diving the set `S` into two disjoint sets, `S₁` and `S₂`. The set `S₁` would contain `0₁` and the subscript `₄` elements. The set `S₂` would contain the subscript `₂` and subscript `₃` elements:

```
S₁ = {0₁, ¯3₄, ¯2₄, ¯1₄, 0₄, 1₄, 2₄, 3₄}
S₂ = {¯1₂, 0₂, 1₂, ¯2₃, ¯1₃, 0₃, 1₃, 2₃}
S  = S₁ ∪ S₂
```

Now, we can solve this problem separately for `S₁` and `S₂`. However, we want to do it in such a way that the solutions are similar. Thus, when we combine them we can take advantage of the similarity to reduce the number of operations involved. Here's the solution that I came up with:

[image: Solution]

There are two things to notice about my solution:

1. All the zero elements belong to the `C'D'` column. Hence, it's easy to select the rest of the elements using `C+D`. This will come in handy later.
2. The negative elements are always in the `B` row, and in the same column as the corresponding positive elements. This makes negation and checking whether negative easy.

Anyway, here are the operations implemented using bitwise operators where `(A, B, C, D) ∈ S`:

```
(A, B, C, D) < 0 = B (C + D)

¯(A, B, C, D)    = (A, B ^ (C + D), C, D)

(A, B, C, D) + M =
    E = C D
    N = M'
    (A, B N + M E,
        C N + M (A ^ C ^ D ^ A E),
        D N + M D' (B + C))

(A, B, C, D) ¢ M = M D (A + C)
```

The number of operations required for addition, carry, negation and comparison are 18, 3, 2 and 2 respectively. Notice that for negation we only need to modify `B` and for addition we don't need to modify `A`. [Common subexpression elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) and xor operations are used reduce operations.

I don't know whether it's possible to do better than this. This is the best solution that I came up with.